# Reporting Services stop working as soon as .Net sp 2.0 is installed

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2007, .net-2.0

I use reporting services integrated with SharePoint. All reports work fine. The thing is that as soon as I installed the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 (NetFx20SP2_x64.exe), I get an error page when accessing the reports saying the following:

> An unexpected error occured while connecting to the report server. Verify that the report server is configured for SharePoint integrated mode. --> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Any ideas why installing the sp2 for .Net 2.0 is causing this error?

Edit:
I also get the following line in MOSS logs

> AppDomainUnloadListener.RegisterSelf() entered lock(this=15368010).

Answer (score 0):

please see the below links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384252%28SQL.100%29.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/7e77fe54-74ee-437c-a985-03dd04e9f35c/